# Creating WP plugin to customize existing plugin

Tags: wordpress

I'm currently using a WordPress plugin that outputs some HTML in a search. The outputted HTML has a 
 tag that I'd like removed. Upon talking with the plugin developer who has been extremely helpful, I was informed that the code was "pluggable" and that I could create a plugin that outputs the proper HTML. I was told to then drop the shortcode for the new plugin right before the shortcode that triggers the original plugin.

The function within the plugin that outputs the current HTML is below (AMR users.)

```
function amr_show_filters_alt($cols,$icols,$ulist,$filtercol = array()) { 
    $filters = amr_get_filters ($cols,$icols,$ulist,$filtercol);
    $html = '';
    if (empty($filters)) return '';
    $cols = amr_users_get_column_headings  ($ulist, $cols, $icols);    
    foreach ($icols as $ic => $cv) { 
        if (!empty($filters[$cv]))
            $html     .= '<label for="filter_'.$cv.'">'.$cols[$ic].'</label>'.$filters[$cv].'<br />';

    }

return($html);        
}
```

You'll see a 
 tag near the end that I'd like removed. Basically, what is the proper process for creating a new function to override the one above. The code below was an attempt to remove the 
 tag from the $html variable but unfortunately, it didn't produce the results I was looking for.

```
add_shortcode('pullquote_shortcode', 'pqsc_process_shortcode');

function pqsc_process_shortcode() {
    $html     .= '<label for="filter_'.$cv.'">'.$cols[$ic].'</label>'.$filters[$cv];
    return($html)
}
```

Any assistance and guidance on the correct process would be very much appreciated :)

Thank you.

Comment: If the function above is wrapped with `if (!function_exists('amr_show_filters_alt"))` then you can simply "redeclare" the function, that is load a function with the same name before they load theirs, thereby overriding it.

Comment: Thank you for the response Tim. The code I have above actually works in that it adds the html to the page. In other words, if I set the word "SMILE" to equal the $html variable, those letters would be outputted onto the page. However, it doesn't replace or override the code outputted by the plugin. It appears to only add. Ultimately, how can I specifically target the plugins versions of the code and replace it with my own (as in no <br> tags)? Thanks again

Comment: Sounds like their function is still firing, therefore you're just adding to the $html data (in addition to theirs). Perhaps try removing their function.. if they have `add_action('hook','function_name')` you can remove it with `remove_action('hook','function_name')`